# Set or Send GPS Location for Android-x86 VM

Tags: android, gps, android-x86, adb

I've got Android X86 9.0r2 running in a VM. I'd like to test the effect of various locations from GPS on an app.

I've connected to it using Python's adb_shell from another VM:

```
>>> device.shell('echo TEST')
'TEST\n'
```

When I try geo fix, it says geo not found:

```
device.shell('geo fix 1.2 3.4')
'/system/bin/sh: geo: not found\n'
```

I'm having trouble finding any info on how to do GPS on Android-x86. I've seen a couple of posts about downloading those 'GPS Spoof' apps, but i'd like to set it myself if possible.

In this post [How do I set/send geolocation parameters lat/long to an Android-x86 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348533/how-do-i-set-send-geolocation-parameters-lat-long-to-an-android-x86-emulator) one of the commenters, bahram, says "geo fix command will not be recognized in Android x-86" but does not elaborate.

I've heard Android X86 supports GPS. How do we work with it?

Answer (score 0):

If it has a GPS receiver, you can use a software-defined radio (SDR) like the HackRF One along with the gps-sdr-sim GitHub project to simulate GPS signals.